# Android KitKat emulator native library JNI ERROR (app bug)

Tags: android, android-emulator, java-native-interface, dalvik, android-4.4-kitkat

While testing my app with Android 4.4.2 API level 19 emulator, first call to native code causes a crash. This is the logcat:

```
01-29 12:12:32.639: E/ALLOC(1232): Requiring 1228800bytes
01-29 12:12:32.639: D/dalvikvm(1232): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/it.jcsoftmobile.snailcamera.snailcamerapro-1/liblowlevelpixelworks.so 0xb4cd9cc8
01-29 12:12:32.639: D/dalvikvm(1232): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/it.jcsoftmobile.snailcamera.snailcamerapro-1/liblowlevelpixelworks.so 0xb4cd9cc8
01-29 12:12:32.639: D/dalvikvm(1232): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/it.jcsoftmobile.snailcamera.snailcamerapro-1/liblowlevelpixelworks.so 0xb4cd9cc8, skipping init
01-29 12:12:32.679: E/dalvikvm(1232): JNI ERROR (app bug): negative buffer capacity: -5457750921690562560
01-29 12:12:32.679: I/dalvikvm(1232): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
01-29 12:12:32.679: I/dalvikvm(1232):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0xb4a2aca8 self=0xb70c4380
01-29 12:12:32.689: I/dalvikvm(1232):   | sysTid=1232 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=-1225698988
01-29 12:12:32.689: I/dalvikvm(1232):   | state=R schedstat=( 1140000000 1520000000 1339 ) utm=83 stm=31 core=0
01-29 12:12:32.729: I/dalvikvm(1232):   at it.jcsoftmobile.snailcamera.ImageLab.NativeAlloc(Native Method)
```

This is the logcat of the same piece of code, same app, same screen-size emulator, ... the only thing that differs is Android version (4.3):

```
01-28 19:52:51.543: E/ALLOC(12661): Requiring 1228800bytes
01-28 19:52:51.563: D/dalvikvm(12661): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/it.jcsoftmobile.snailcamera.snailcamerapro-1/liblowlevelpixelworks.so 0x416e2fd0
01-28 19:52:51.613: D/dalvikvm(12661): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/it.jcsoftmobile.snailcamera.snailcamerapro-1/liblowlevelpixelworks.so 0x416e2fd0
01-28 19:52:51.613: D/dalvikvm(12661): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/it.jcsoftmobile.snailcamera.snailcamerapro-1/liblowlevelpixelworks.so 0x416e2fd0, skipping init
01-28 19:52:51.922: D/dalvikvm(12661): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 68K, 4% free 3447K/3584K, paused 302ms, total 303ms
01-28 19:52:51.922: I/dalvikvm-heap(12661): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.865MB for 460816-byte allocation
```

I read something about ART vm, but i think this is not the case, because logcat explicitly tags both outputs as "dalvikvm".

My app was running ok on every tested devices and emulators, starting from GB 2.3.3 to JB 4.3, KitKat is the first version that gave me problems.

Maybe KitKat has a different loadLibrary management? Should i implement (i dunno how!) JNI_OnLoad?

Any idea?

**EDIT**

I tested my app on a Nexus 7 with KK 4.4.2, and it's working fine.

Here's the C code that generates the exception:

```
jobject Java_my_package_NativeAlloc(JNIEnv* env, jlong numBytes) {
    void *ptr = (char*)malloc(numBytes);
    return (*env)->NewDirectByteBuffer(env, ptr, numBytes);
}
```

and here's the Java code that calls it:

```
public native static ByteBuffer NativeAlloc(int size);
```

There is of course an issue, as Java *int size* (32-bit) becomes a JNI *jlong numBytes* (64-bit), my fault.
But why this code worked fine until 4.4.2 emulator?

Comment: Sounds like a bad value being passed in for the "capacity" argument to `NewDirectByteBuffer`.  Can you show the code that calls it?  See also line 2695 in https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/kitkat-release/vm/Jni.cpp .

Comment: @fadden The value passed should be the same for all tested platforms, why should it work everywhere except on kitkat emulator? Anyway, the code is a simple malloc(), i think the problem is in the conversion between java int and C size_t (that is platform dependant!).

Comment: @j.c. - most likely it worked because you were also omitting the jclass argument, and in the reshuffle of mismatched bits you were accidentally getting errors that balanced out on some platforms but not on others.

Comment: Chris Stratton's answer is correct.  Fix the function declaration and your code should start working everywhere.

Comment: @ChrisStratton yes, that's the point. Fixed using long in java side and adding jclass in native code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function prototype is incorrect, causing your arguments to be intermixed in a platform-dependent way and the requested size to be potentially corrupted.

```
public native static ByteBuffer NativeAlloc(int size);
```

Should correspond to

```
jobject Java_my_package_NativeAlloc(JNIEnv* env, jclass someClass, jint numBytes)
```

By omitting the `jclass` argument you risk corrupting the other arguments.

This may have balanced out the jint/jlong mistake in your code on some platforms, but not on others.

Comment: Thanx, this absolutely fixed my bug and explained what happened.

Comment: ARM EABI passes first 4 args in registers, but 64-bit values must start in an even-numbered register.  Based on Java declaration, VM is calling with r0=jnienv, r1=class, r2=32-bit size, r3=unused.  Based on C++ declaration, gcc is expecting r0=jnienv, r1=unused, r2/r3=64-bit size.  So your native function is getting the 32-bit size in the low half, and whatever happened to be in r3 in the upper half.  Some platforms happened to have a zero in r3, some had what looks like a pointer, so you get inconsistent behavior.

Comment: @fadden +1, this is the most complete and clear answer i was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, but... Your app is `Requiring 1228800bytes` and `-5457750921690562560`  is a 64-bit number, whose lower part is 1228800 (0x12C000) and the higher part is 0xB4422C74. Probably a 64-bit fetch is done from an address containing a 32-bit number (the length). If you could place 0 after the length, this would probably solve the problem. But you have to locate the place.

Does the bug happen on a 64-bit desktop system? If so, you could try a 32-bit version.

Comment: @# interesting point... I'm working on a 64-bit linux system.
So do you think this issue could be due to a different integer management of the 4.4 Dalvikvm?

Comment: Probably if you install a 32-bit guest under, say, VirtualBox, it will get better. I also suggest reporting a bug.

Comment: Do you think it's an emulator issue? Will my app run under Nexus 5?

Comment: Most likely yes. It is a good idea to try your app on a real device, if you have one.

Comment: Yes, you are right! On a Nexus 7 4.4.2 it works, i'm gonna reporting the bug.

Comment: This is an insightful investigation, but the true problem only became apparent when the offending code was later edited into the question: it's not an android bug, but rather application programmer error in creating java and native declarations which do not match. Depending on the platform-specific calling convention, this may or may not result in the arguments being corrupted in the way you have noticed.